# What is the purpose of the Set-Link-Info message in PPTP? The RFC seems to contradict itself in regard to this message

Tags: gre, ppp

A PPTP connection transports payload data by wrapping it into PPP and then sending it over a previously negotiated Enhanced GRE link.

As per PPTP RFC, the following holds true:

> The encapsulated PPP
> packets are essentially PPP data packets less any media specific
> framing elements.  No HDLC flags, bit insertion, **control characters,
> or control character escapes** are included. No CRCs are sent through
> the tunnel.

- [Section 4. Tunnel Protocol Operation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2637#section-4)

So nothing of the PPP data must be escaped and all characters are treated as ordinary characters and not control characters.

However PPTP also defines a `Set-Link-Info` message in [section 2.15. Set-Link-Info](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2637#section-2.15) and the only purpose of this message is to set the ACCMs, which stands for Asynchronous Control Character Map. It also defines, that unless this message is sent, the other side shall assume `0xFFFFFFFF` as default.

The only purpose of the ACCM is to tell the other side which control characters must be escaped but section 4 forbids escaping of control characters, so what purpose has setting an ACCM other than zero? And what behavior is expected if the default value says all characters below ASCII code 32 must be escaped, yet escaping is forbidden?

All implementations I found simply ignore the ACCM entirely and never escape anything, yet this makes the `Set-Link-Info` message completely pointless as it will never have an effect. Can someone shine a light on this contradiction?

Relevant RFCs:

- [Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP) [RFC 2637]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2637)
- [The Point-to-Point Protocol (PPP) [RFC 1661]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1661)
- [PPP in HDLC-like Framing [RFC 1662]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1662)
- [Generic Routing Encapsulation (GRE) [RFC 2784]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2784)
- [Key and Sequence Number Extensions to GRE [RFC 2890]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2890)

Comment: I don't have an answer for this, but it's worth noting that many protocols incorporate features that the author(s) think could be useful, but prove latter to not be needed and are never used (or reserve fields / space for future usage and  are also not used).

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin There is only one answer and I already commented it, didn't I?

Comment: We are doing the year-end cleanup, and pasting the comment in on any question that has unaccepted answers. I do not really look at the question or answer because I have too many to go through. Also, you may have discovered the answer on your own, and you could post and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin If you just copy and paste this, without even looking at the question or the answers, you should mention that in the pasted comment, just like one would mention if a comment was auto generated by the server.

Comment: Even if I had read this question and answer (I have now), I still would have pasted it in because you may have discovered the answer on your own, and simply forgot to put it here. There are hundreds that I have got answered and accepted that way.

Answer (score 1):

> The encapsulated PPP packets are essentially PPP data packets less any
> media specific framing elements. No HDLC flags, bit insertion, control
> characters, or control character escapes are included. No CRCs are
> sent through the tunnel.

That means that PPTP itself doesn't use any control characters within the transported PPP packets. All signaling is taken over to PPTP.

ACCM is used to enable transparent transport of character sequences resembling control characters for the underlying asynchronous link. These must be escaped or the link breaks (think of the Hayes ~+++~AT sequence).

Comment: I know what ACCM is and what it is good for but where would ACCM be applied at a PPTP link? I tried setting different values for ACCM but no matter what value I set, the other side sends everything unescaped and expects everything to be sent unescaped. Tried with 4 different VPN hardware gateways and 3 different PPTP software implementations. Also PPP negotiates the async control character map itself, also over a PPTP GRE link. It requires no ACCM support on link level, the link level will already get escaped characters if required.